# How can I get a list of all directory names and/or all files in a specific directory in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, filesystems, dir

There are two things I want to do:

1. Get a list of all the directory names within a directory, and
2. Get a list of all the file names within a directory

How can I do this in MATLAB?

Right now, I'm trying:

```
dirnames = dir(image_dir);
```

but that returns a list of objects, I think. `size(dirnames)` returns the number of attributes, and `dirnames.name` only returns the name of the first directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [DIR](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html) actually returns a [structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html) with one structure element per file or subdirectory in the given directory. When [getting data from a structure array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-38.html#br1v5pf-1), accessing a field with dot notation will return a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br2js35-1.html) of field values with one value per structure element. This comma-separated list can be [collected into a vector](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-84864.html) by placing it in square brackets `[]` or a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html) by placing it in curly braces `{}`.

I usually like to get a list of file or subdirectory names in a directory by making use of [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1), like so:

```
dirInfo = dir(image_dir);            %# Get structure of directory information
isDir = [dirInfo.isdir];             %# A logical index the length of the 
                                     %#   structure array that is true for
                                     %#   structure elements that are
                                     %#   directories and false otherwise
dirNames = {dirInfo(isDir).name};    %# A cell array of directory names
fileNames = {dirInfo(~isDir).name};  %# A cell array of file names
```

Answer (score 2):

No. you are incorrect about what dirnames.name returns.

```
D = dir;
```

This is a structure array. If you want a list of which are directories, do this

```
isdirlist = find(vertcat(D.isdir));
```

Or I could have used cell2mat here. Note that if you just try D.name, is returns a comma separated list. You can get all of the names as a cell array simply though.

```
nameslist = {D.name};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "image_dir" is the name of a directory, the following code shows you how to determine which items are directories and which are files and how to get their names.  Once you've gotten that far, building a list of only directories or only files is straightforward.

```
dirnames = dir(image_dir);
for(i = 1:length(dirnames))
   if(dirnames(i).isdir == true)
      % It's a subdirectory
      % The name of the subdirectory can be accessed as dirnames(i).name
      % Note that both '.' and '..' are subdirectories of any directory and
      % should be ignored
   else
      % It's a filename
      % The filename is dirnames(i).name
   end
end
```